# Strategy to develop localy and test remote keeping the company private framework secure

Tags: eclipse, git, github, ftp, amazon-ec2

Today my team is working in eclipse rse with a intranet server (php). We do this to keep secure the company private framework (don't distributing it), that is used to develop every application.

The application's code stay in the remote server, and we develop with ftp.

It's hard to work with the delay in ctrl + space (autocomplete), file search, and the poor support to git or others tools  in a eclipse remote project so we recently decided to work with amazon ec2/elasticbeanstalk and github, but is impractical at every save, to commit and re-deploy the entire application to execute the tests.

How can i automate the deploy of my application to test it?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at Capistrano? http://www.capistranorb.com/

Comment: looks nice... did you ever heard about http://www.vagrantup.com/?

Comment: No, but it seems just a tool for building VM with the same environment. Is it something related to this question?